# Handling asynchronous functions in node.js 6.11.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the function below ad.getUsersForGroup(...) is an async function. Inside its callback I use teamId, the function ends up using the last teamId. I think this is because by the time the function runs and the callback is entered all the iterations are completed. How can I get the correct teamId in the callback. I have console.logged where the issue is.

```
 function getUsersFromAdTeams(adDictionary) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            var opts = {
                attributes: ['name', 'mail', 'thumbnailPhoto', 'title', 'uid', 'sAMAccountName', 'displayName']
            }
            let promises = [];
            
            for (teamId in adDictionary) {
                // console.log(teamId)
                let team = adDictionary[teamId];
                if(Object.keys(team.subteam).length > 0){
                    let subteams = team.subteam;
                    for (subteamId in subteams) {
                        let subteam = subteams[subteamId]
                        
                        ad.getUsersForGroup(opts, subteam.AdName, function(err, users) {
                            if(err) {
                                console.log(err)
                            }
                            users.map(user => {
                                englishJobTitle = user.title.split('|')[1];
                                hasImage = Buffer.isBuffer(user.thumbnailPhoto);
                                subteam.users.members[user.uid] = {
                                    name: user.name,
                                    mail: user.mail,
                                    jobTitle: englishJobTitle,
                                    hasImage: hasImage
                                }
                            })
                            console.log(teamId); //prints last teamId multiple times
                        })
                        console.log(teamId);
                    }
                }

        }
        catch(err) {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
}
```

I have an object `adDictionary` that has information about teams and subteams from an active directory.

adDictionary is an object. The keys of this dictionary point to an object, I call team. team has a property `subteam` which has the same properties as team but not subteam. (team can have subteam. A subteam cannot). This function will populate both team and subteam with users. It is only partially completed, I got stuck on the inner loop. Here is a real snippet of what adDictionary looks like before the function runs. Notice how in users, `lead` and `members` are empty. This function will fill `members`

```
  '36':
   { AdName: 'DF-DEV',
     displayName: 'DF',
     users: { lead: {}, members: {} },
     subteam: {} },
  '37':
   { AdName: 'Team-NINJA',
     displayName: 'Ninja',
     users: { lead: {}, members: {} },
     subteam: {} },
  '38':
   { AdName: 'Team-GDD-Dev',
     displayName: 'GDD Dev',
     users: { lead: {}, members: {} },
     subteam: { '39': [Object], '40': [Object], '41': [Object] } },
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get `1 1 1 3 3 3 5 5 5` (each number on a separate line).  That is exactly as expected.  The `evens.forEach()` runs for each of the odds, so your callback gets called 3 times for each odd.  Please show a real problem (not a made-up problem) and describe what you want the result to be and we can help you with a solution.  In general, you don't want to use `.forEach()` with asynchronous operations inside because it is not async aware or promise aware so you don't have any control over things.  Instead, use a regular `for` loop or a specific asynchronous looping function.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're on node.js v6 when v12 is the current LTS and v14 is already out?

Comment: Hi thanks, I have added my real code. I'm using `for (teamId in adDictionary)`

Comment: @jfriend00 I am adding some features to this existing codebase

Comment: First thing is change all the places where you have code like `for (teamId in adDictionary)` to `for (let teamId in adDictionary)`.  And, add `"use strict";` as the very first line of your file to tell Javascript to stop you from doing evil things (which in this case is auto-declaring globals).

Comment: What kind of object is `adDictionary` and `subteam`?  Are they arrays?  Are they plain objects with properties?  Custom objects?

Comment: What is the overall objective of this code?  Describe in words what it is supposed to do.

Comment: That seems to have resolved it. Thank you! I spent a few months working in python so that looked normal to me.

Comment: Do you realize that you have no proper error handling for your `ad.getUsersForGroup()` call?

Comment: yes thanks, I will reject instead of console.log on error

Comment: It seems you have more work to do because you're calling an asynchronous function inside a loop.  You will probably need to promisify the async function so you can use `Promise.all()` with it to know when everything is done.  In fact, it's inside a double loop so you've got lots more work to do.

Comment: promisify as in wrap the async function in a new promise, push the promises to an array and call `promise.all()`?

Comment: Generally yes, but any more advice would need to know what actual output you're trying to get here with the double loop (what the objective is for this function).  Promisifying should be done outside the function so you're just calling a promisified version in your main logic flow.

Comment: I have added more information below the code

Comment: You're making progress in describing the data, but I still don't know what the purpose of this function is?  What are you trying to get out of it or what is it supposed to accomplish?

Comment: The purpose is to add the retrieved users to the users property inside of adDictionary (right now, only for subteams). 

Inside of users.members would be an object where each key is the users name which points to an object with more information about the user

Comment: I would expect, that this would be done at this step

                            `users.map(user => {
                                subteam.users.members[user.uid] = {
                                    name: user.name,
                                    mail: user.mail,
                                    jobTitle: englishJobTitle,
                                    hasImage: hasImage
                                }`

Comment: Do you really have to use node v6 where you can't even use `async` and `await`?

Answer (score 1):

Here would be my suggested code:

```
const promisify = require('util').promisify;
ad.getUsersForGroupP = promisify(ad.getUsersForGroup);

function getUsersFromAdTeams(adDictionary) {
    var opts = {
        attributes: ['name', 'mail', 'thumbnailPhoto', 'title', 'uid', 'sAMAccountName', 'displayName']
    }
    let promises = [];

    for (let teamId in adDictionary) {
        let team = adDictionary[teamId];
        let subteams = team.subteam;
        for (let subteamId in subteams) {
            let subteam = subteams[subteamId];
            let p = ad.getUsersForGroupP(opts, subteam.AdName).then(function(users) {
                users.map(user => {
                    subteam.users.members[user.uid] = {
                        name: user.name,
                        mail: user.mail,
                        jobTitle: user.title.split('|')[1],
                        hasImage: Buffer.isBuffer(user.thumbnailPhoto)
                    }
                })
            }).catch(function(err) {
                // log and rethrow error to keep the promise as rejected
                console.log(err);
                throw err;
            });
            promises.push(p);
        }
    }
    // return a promise that knows when we're entirely done
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Description of changes:

1. Promisify `ad.getUsersForGroup()` so we can use promise logic within the function
2. Declare all variables used within this function locally so there are no accidental globals created here.  This is particularlky important with the `for` loop.
3. Use `let` when declared the `for` loop index so that it will be local to each invocation of the loop and can thus be used within asynchronous functions without confusion or error
4. Collect an array of promises from the asynchronous operation
5. Use `Promise.all()` on that array so you can return a master promise that lets the caller know when everything is done or when there's been an error.
6. Remove some temporary variables that are not needed.
7. Remove `if` test on the `Object.keys()` as the `for` loop will already cover the case of no keys to iterate.
8. Change `.map()` to `.forEach()`.  If you're not using the returned array from `.map()`, then there is no reason to use `.map()` and create that array, so just use `.forEach()`.
9. When calling the promisified `ad.getUsersForGroupP()` use `.then()` to access the results.

Comment: I wasn't able to use promisify. That's in a later version of node. I wrapped the function in a promise though and it worked well. Thank you!

Comment: @perpetualrag - Since it looks like you may be new here, if this answer helped you solve your problem, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure here.